# meson can not find windows resource compiler on linux

Tags: linux, windows, cross-compiling, meson-build

I'm trying to cross compile an application with meson 0.51.1

My build system: Linux

Host System: Windows

The application depends on freetype2 from meson wrap db:
https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v1/projects/freetype2/2.9.1/1/get_wrap

I'm keep getting the following error:

```
meson.build: ERROR: Could not find Windows resource compiler
```

The complaint is about the following line in the freetype's meson.build file:

```
  winmod = import('windows')
  base_sources += [
    'builds/windows/ftdebug.c',
    winmod.compile_resources('src/base/ftver.rc'),
  ]
```

My cross file looks like:

```
[binaries]
c = ['ccache', 'i686-w64-mingw32-gcc']
cpp = ['ccache', 'i686-w64-mingw32-g++']
ar = 'i686-w64-mingw32-ar'
strip = 'i686-w64-mingw32-strip'
exe_wrapper = 'WINEPREFIX=~/.wine64 wine'
windres = 'i686-w64-mingw32-windres'

[properties]
needs_exe_wrapper = true

[host_machine]
system = 'windows'
cpu_family = 'i686'
cpu = 'i686'
endian = 'little'
```

i686-w64-mingw32-windres is installed:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-windres --version
GNU windres (GNU Binutils) 2.32.51.20190707
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

I tried to set the WINDRES variable as described hear https://mesonbuild.com/Windows-module.html. It does not help either.

Comment: Do you actually have `i686-w64-mingw32-windres` on your machine? Perform `find <toolchain dir> -name i686-w64-mingw32-windres` to verify.

Comment: yes I do ```$ find /usr -name i686-w64-mingw32-windres``` gives me ```/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-windres```. Putting the absolute path in the crossfile does not help.